# Move specific folder using PnPjs in a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, folder, pnpjs

I have add below PnP JS code but it's not working correctly and throwing error "Property 'moveByPath' does not exist on type 'Folder'".

```
await web.getFolderByServerRelativePath(oldPath).moveByPath(`${path}/${name}`, keepBoth).then(() => {

});
```

Comment: which PnP js version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **moveTo()** like below:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/folders";

// destination is a server-relative url of a new folder
const destinationUrl = `/sites/my-site/SiteAssets/new-folder`;

await sp.web.rootFolder.folders.getByName("SiteAssets").folders.getByName("My Folder").moveTo(destinationUrl);
```

**Source**: [@pnp/sp/folders - move](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/folders/#move)

**OR**

Use **moveByPath** like below:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/folders";

// destination is a server-relative url of a new folder
const destinationUrl = `/sites/my-site/SiteAssets/new-folder`;

await sp.web.rootFolder.folders.getByName("SiteAssets").folders.getByName("My Folder").moveByPath(destinationUrl, true);
```

**Source**: [@pnp/sp/folders - move by path](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/folders/#move-by-path)

**Note**:

1. **moveByPth** is added in version 2.0.2. So, use latest version of PnP JS.

[PnP JS - Change Log](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#202---2020-01-23)

Comment: Which place added source path ??

Comment: Source path is --> Folder with name "My Folder" under "SiteAssets" library.

Comment: Use latest version of PnP JS. check my updated answer.

Comment: Update version for sp-pnp-js ?

Comment: Yes, you can use updated version.You can update it using `npm i @pnp/pnpjs` or `npm i @pnp/pnpjs@latest`.

Comment: But Throwing error "Error making HttpClient request in queryable"

Comment: At which line it is throwing error? can you please add the updated code you are using to your question by editing the original question?

Comment: var srcPath="DTList/9654/PT@1833";
 var destpath="DTList/PT@1618/Top";

await sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativePath(srcPath).moveTo(destpath).then(() => {
  
            }).catch((error: any) => { 
              debugger
              console.log(error.message);
            });

Note :- DTList is document library and error throwing catch block so not executing await block.

Comment: Try using: `await sp.web.rootFolder.folders.getByName("DTList").folders.getByName("9654").folders.getByName("PT@1833").moveTo("/sites/<site name>/DTList/PT@1618/Top");`

Comment: Still facing issue....

status of 404 () :- tenanturl/sites/<site name>/SitePages/_api/web/rootFolder/folders('DTList')/folders('9654654654')/folders('PT%401833')?$select=ServerRelativeUrl